# what arose adwords api AuthenticationError?

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I tried to run the example script  of adwords_api_python, unfortunately met following erros:

```
[root@centos adwords_api_python_13.2.0]# python get_related_keywords.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_related_keywords.py", line 56, in <module>
    page = targeting_idea_service.Get(selector)[0]
  File "adspygoogle/adwords/TargetingIdeaService.py", line 79, in Get
    'TargetingIdea', self._loc, request)
  File "adspygoogle/adwords/AdWordsWebService.py", line 256, in CallMethod
    self.__ManageSoap(buf, start_time, stop_time, error)
  File "adspygoogle/adwords/AdWordsWebService.py", line 125, in __ManageSoap
    raise e
adspygoogle.adwords.AdWordsErrors.AdWordsAuthenticationError: AuthenticationError.NOT_ADS_USER @ ; trigger:'738513257043' Service[TargetingIdeaService.get]
```

- I have applied a MCC account, and
  applied the adowrds api token
  (status: waiting for the examination
  and approval).
- I have run the    "config.py" script
  to set    authentication headers.

**Should i wait until they accept my application?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to wait until your application is approved. Then you will be able to find your developer token by logging into the MCC account and looking in the "API Center" section of the "My Account" tab.

It was taking up to two weeks to approve the token a few years back but it's usually much faster now.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is create a ["Test Account"](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/test-accounts?hl=en) while your waiting for your MCC account to be approved. You don't have to wait for approval on a test account plus you're not developing against your production account;)